# Bootstrap position problem : content overlaping and not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap and would like to have responsive working good but cant acheive it.
My problem is that content is overlaping (text over image) and text is not responsive (however font size is in "em").
Besides, text is getting out of the canvas and the anchor point for resising seems to be on a corner and not centered.
I try to have a 100% height canvas without scrolling for a landing page.

here is the Codepend exemple.

```js
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-157cd5b….js"></script>
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  padding: 50px;
}




}

.card{
    

}



.card h3{
  font-weight: 600;
}



.card-1{

}

.card-2{

}

.card-1 {
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 7.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
  width: 600px;
}
h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: -125px;
    left: -80px;
    color: #EFDE74;
    z-index: -1;
    font-size: 8.15em;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
h3 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1;
    bottom: 160px;;
  
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
  }
  p {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
  bottom: 158px;;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 110px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-1">
        <h1> Rapffhaël</h1>
        <h2>chemonni</h2>
        <h3>collection 2017 <br> duality</h3>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde quis, delectus facere
                            neque sunt commodi quae
                            culpa dolores doloribus magnam?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card card-2">
       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100%; float: right;">
       
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```